# UIView background color in Swift

Tags: swift, ios8, xcode6

Is there a way to set the UIView background color with Swift?

I know that in Objective-C, you would use `self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];`, but that does not work the same way in Swift. I have looked around and because Swift is only about a week old, I cannot find an answer.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: You are making excuses. ;-) I found the answer to this question on the first day. This is how I found it: In Xcode, in your code editor write `UIColor`, then hold the command key and click on the word `UIColor`. You will jump right into the "header" where you'll find all the available functions.

Answer (score 135, accepted):

```
self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
```

In Swift 3:

```
self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
```

Comment: how can i use hexadecimal?

Comment: @Igor Ronner UIColor(red: 0xFF / 0xFF, green: 0x00 / 0xFF, blue: 0x00 / 0xFF, alpha: 0xFF / 0xFF)

Comment: In swift 4:-  
self.view.backgroundColor =  .red

Answer (score 27):

Try This, It worked like a charm! for me,

The simplest way to add **backgroundColor** programmatically by using **ColorLiteral**.

You need to add the property **ColorLiteral**, Xcode will prompt you with a whole list of colors in which you can choose any color. The advantage of doing this is we use lesser code, add HEX values or RGB. You will also get the recently used colors from the storyboard.

Follow steps ,

1) Add below line of code in **viewDidLoad()** ,

```
self.view.backgroundColor = ColorLiteral
```

and clicked on enter button .

2) Display square box next to =

[image]

3) When Clicked on Square Box **Xcode** will prompt you with a whole list of colors which you can choose any colors also you can set **HEX** values or **RGB**

[image]

4) You can successfully set the colors .

[image]

Hope this will help some one to set backgroundColor in different ways.

Comment: I love this tip. Thank-you. I was a little confused by the first step using "ColorLiteral" until finding "Color Literal" in auto completion.

Answer (score 19):

I see that this question is solved, but, I want to add some information than can help someone.

if you want use hex to set background color, I found this function and work:

```
func UIColorFromHex(rgbValue:UInt32, alpha:Double=1.0)->UIColor {
    let red = CGFloat((rgbValue & 0xFF0000) >> 16)/256.0
    let green = CGFloat((rgbValue & 0xFF00) >> 8)/256.0
    let blue = CGFloat(rgbValue & 0xFF)/256.0

    return UIColor(red:red, green:green, blue:blue, alpha:CGFloat(alpha))
}
```

I use this function as follows:

```
view.backgroundColor = UIColorFromHex(0x323232,alpha: 1)
```

some times you must use `self`:

```
self.view.backgroundColor = UIColorFromHex(0x323232,alpha: 1)
```

Well that was it, I hope it helps someone .

sorry for my bad english.

this work on iOS 7.1+

Comment: One quick thing to note, need to add the param name in:
```UIColorFromHex(rgbValue: 0x323232, alpha: 1)```

Answer (score 16):

You can use the line below which goes into a closure (`viewDidLoad`, `didLayOutSubViews`, etc):

```
self.view.backgroundColor = .redColor()
```

**EDIT** Swift 3:

```
view.backgroundColor = .red
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use this extension as an alternative if you're dealing with RGB value.

```
extension UIColor {
    static func rgb(red: CGFloat, green: CGFloat, blue: CGFloat) -> UIColor {
        return UIColor(red: red/255, green: green/255, blue: blue/255, alpha: 1)
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

In Swift 4, just as simple as Swift 3:

```
self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.brown
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to set your custom RGB color try this:

`self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 20/255.0, green: 106/255.0, blue: 93/255.0, alpha: 1)`

Don't forget to keep /255.0 for every color

Answer (score 1):

The response by @Miknash and @wolfgang gutierrez barrera was helpful to me. Only difference was I had to add `rgbValue:` to the function call.

`UIColorFromHex(rgbValue: 0xA6D632,alpha: 1 )` like so

Answer (score 0):

Since the Xcode 13, the shortcut ColorLiteral does not work anymore.

Now, you have to use this shortcut:

```
let color = #colorLiteral()
```

The color display appears after writing the first "(" and tapping the symbol

[image]