# Self.View.BackgroundColor won't change

Tags: swift, background-color

The following code should change my view's background color:

```
self.view.backgroundColor == UIColor.blackColor()
```

Why does this not work?

Comment: Presumably, you've already [looked at this similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24112272/uiview-background-color-in-swift) to find this snippet. Have you also tried without `self.`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`self` needs to be some sort of view controller and you need to get rid of the double equals sign:

```
self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
```

Where are you setting the `backgroundColor` property? `viewDidLoad()` would be a good spot.

Comment: i can't put it in viewDidLoad , Cus I Want to change it with button touch